# Spring Cloud config feign fallback(CircuitBreaker) rule

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

Now I use feign with hystrix, it turns out that Circuit will turn to Open status when fallback method invoke 20 times in 5s. How can I change this rule. For example, let the Circuit status turn to open when fallback method invoke 50 times in 5s, or by fallback callback rate.
Here is my main java code.

ConsumerApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@RibbonClients({@RibbonClient(name = "cloud-provider", configuration = CloudProviderConfiguration.class)})
public class ConsumerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

UserFeignClient.java

```
@FeignClient(name = "cloud-provider", fallback = UserFeignClient.HystrixClientFallback.class)
public interface UserFeignClient {
    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    BaseResponse findByIdFeign(@RequestParam("id") Long id);

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    BaseResponse addUserFeign(UserVo userVo);

    @Component
    class HystrixClientFallback implements UserFeignClient {
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HystrixClientFallback.class);

        @Override
        public BaseResponse findByIdFeign(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
            BaseResponse response = new BaseResponse();
            response.setMessage("disable!!!!");
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        public BaseResponse addUserFeign(UserVo userVo) {
            BaseResponse response = new BaseResponse();
            response.setMessage("disable");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The configuration parameters are described here https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration

`hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds` changes the 5 second window you are seeing.

`hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold` defaults to 20 requests.

Comment: @spencergibb These properties apply for all feign hystrix clients right? What if I want to change the hystrix property for specific feign clients alone?

Comment: @codingsplash Came here looking for that.